# How to append dictionary of dictionary dynamically in python?

Tags: python

Previously I have initialize like this statically. This is working fine.

```py
dict = {
   
   'telco_recharge_non_wallet': {
   'robi_at' : telco_recharge_non_wallet['robi_at'],
   'tt' : telco_recharge_non_wallet['tt'],
   'bl' : telco_recharge_non_wallet['bl'],
   'gp' : telco_recharge_non_wallet['gp'],
   }  
}
```

I want this like dynamically. (I tried. But could not solve.)

```py
for tel in telcos:
    dict['telco_recharge_non_wallet'] = {
         tel : telco_recharge_non_wallet[tel]
    }
```

Problem is I could not able to append dict of dict. The way I tried just take the last inserted value.

- Input : `print(dict['telco_recharge_non_wallet'])`
- Output :

```
{'robi_at': [['xxx', Decimal('000')], ['xxx', Decimal('000')]]}
{'tt': [['xxx', Decimal('000')], ['xxx', Decimal('000')]]}
{'bl': [['xxx', Decimal('000')], ['xxx', Decimal('000')]]}
{'gp': [['xxx', Decimal('000')], ['xxx', Decimal('000')]]}
```

Comment: can you add your input and required output?

Comment: You should probably not name a dict "dict", because this overwrites the builtin "dict" class.

Comment: did you mean something like `d = {'telco_recharge_non_wallet': {tel: telco_recharge_non_wallet[tel] for tel in telcos}}`?

Comment: @MrFuppes... yes like that... the upper section code is the main code which I am focusing .....

Comment: @PApostol... Yes... thats why I want to append.... but how can I append in such scenario?

Comment: I have added the input/output @Kuldeep Singh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some problem with your code.

1. You shouldn't overwrite the dict class.
2. Your code isn't formatted correctly (this doesn't change anything in Python, but it's difficult to read).

Maybe you're looking for this:

```py
data = {
   'telco_recharge_non_wallet': {
       'robi_at': telco_recharge_non_wallet['robi_at'],
       'tt': telco_recharge_non_wallet['tt'],
       'bl': telco_recharge_non_wallet['bl'],
       'gp': telco_recharge_non_wallet['gp'],
   }  
}

for tel in telcos:
    data['telco_recharge_non_wallet'][tel] = telco_recharge_non_wallet[tel]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
intermediate_dict = {}
for tel in telcos:
    intermediate_dict[tel] = telco_recharge_non_wallet[tel]

final_dict = {'telco_recharge_non_wallet': intermediate_dict}
```